# Workdays for each month in list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, weekday

python newbie here.
I am trying to create a df where 1 column is a month 'YYYY-MM' which I have created in a dict below (tips on generating this using code would be appreciated). 
I am stuck trying to get the weekdays column populated using the month_list.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month_list':['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04']})
df['weekdays'] = ''
```

I tried this code, but this only works for correctly for the first row. (i understand why this is, i just don't know the best way to complete each row correctly)

```
df.weekdays = np.busday_count(month_list[0], month_list[0+1])
df
```

Comment: What is your expected output based on the sample input dataframe?

Comment: Id like to see the count of weekdays in each month. for example, the first month should be 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month_list': pd.date_range('2019-01', '2019-12', freq='MS')})

df['weekdays'] = np.busday_count(df.month_list.values.astype('datetime64[D]'), (df.month_list + MonthEnd(0)).values.astype('datetime64[D]')) + 1
```

Result:

```
   month_list  weekdays
0  2019-01-01        23
1  2019-02-01        20
2  2019-03-01        22
3  2019-04-01        22
4  2019-05-01        23
5  2019-06-01        21
6  2019-07-01        23
7  2019-08-01        23
8  2019-09-01        21
9  2019-10-01        23
10 2019-11-01        22
11 2019-12-01        22
```

Comment: Thanks Stef and jezrael, both solutions are very helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Convert values to datetimes and to strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), then add one month and pass to `np.busday_count`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month_list':['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04']})

month_list = pd.to_datetime(df['month_list'])
a = month_list.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
b = (month_list + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['weekdays'] = np.busday_count(a, b)

print (df)
  month_list  weekdays
0    2019-01        23
1    2019-02        20
2    2019-03        21
3    2019-04        22
```

Only numpy solution:

```
month_list = pd.to_datetime(df['month_list'])

a = month_list.to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
b = a + np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[M]') 

df['weekdays'] = np.busday_count(a, b)
print (df)
  month_list  weekdays
0    2019-01        23
1    2019-02        20
2    2019-03        21
3    2019-04        22
```